# Insert using Ajax is successful but database rows are blank

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

Why does my code successfully save data to database using Ajax, **but all rows are blank**?

**My Form:**

```
<form name="frm" id="frm" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="namaproduk">Nama Produk</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namaproduk" placeholder="Nama Produk">
    <!--<small class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>-->
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="unitproduk">Segment/Unit</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="unitproduk">
      <option value="1">Cabang</option>
      <option value="2">Mikro</option>
      <option value="3">SME</option>
    </select>
    <!--<small id="namaprodukhelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>-->
  </div>
</form>
<div class="col-sm-12 alert" >
    <button type="button" name="saveproduk" id="insertproduk" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right"><span class="fa fa-save">&nbsp;</span> Save Product</button>
</div>
```

**My Ajax :**

```
$("#insertproduk").on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var DataString=$("#frm").serializeArray()
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>saveproduct',
        data: DataString,   
        success: function (data) {
      //jQuery("#attendence_report_holder").html(response);
      alert("success");
    },
    error:function(data){
      alert("failed");
    }
  });
});
```

**My Controller:**

```
public function saveproduct(){
   $this->product_m->saveproduct_m();
}
```

**My Model:**

```
function saveproduct_m(){ 
    $dataproduk = array(
    "namaproduct" => $this->input->post("namaproduk"),
    "idunit" => $this->input->post("unitproduk"));
    echo $result = $this->db->insert("tbl_product",$dataproduk);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's saving as blank because you haven't defined `name` attribute for your fields. Along with `id="namaproduk"` you should also have `name="namaproduk"` for all your fields respectively.

So it should be:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="namaproduk" name="namaproduk" placeholder="Nama Produk">
```

And

```
<select class="form-control" id="unitproduk" name="unitproduk">
```

Comment: thanks so much Milan.. problem solve. Respect. (Thumbsup)

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help! You can upvote and accept this as an answer. :)